# Use CAM with pretrained (VGG16) and make Heatmap with pneumonia

Tags: python, keras, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heatmap.
I've done almost done.
The problem is that when I use **decode_predctions** there is nothing about pneumonia or sth.
Here is my code.

```
from keras.applications.VGG16 import VGG16  
from keras.preprocessing import image   
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions   
import numpy as np 

img_path = 'path.jpg'   
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size(224,224)) 
x = image.img_to_arrray(img)   
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predctions(pred, top=20)[0])
```

That **img_path** is picture of chest x- ray and the output is not related to pneumonia or chest x-ray. I want the reason why and to get the right parameter of **decode_predctions**
Chears guys.

Comment: What does it give you? Do you have more than 20 classes?

Comment: Actually no. There is only 2 classes which are 'pneumonia' and 'normal'. top=20 is just to find pneumonia class but it isn't.  I think I have to make class my ownself but I don't know how to do.

Comment: It helps if you add the output from decode_predictions.